# log multivariate normal differentiation with VAR process

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, expectation-maximization, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am trying to estimate a regime switching model with an autoregressive component using the EM algorithm. The process itself can be presented this way:

$$ r_{t}= A_{n \times (n+1)} \boldsymbol x_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t} \\ where\quad \boldsymbol x_{t-1} = \binom {const} {r_{t-1}}$$

In the normal case with the mean instead of the VAR process the maximization step is straighforward with $\mu$ calculated in each iteration by taking the derivative of the log likelihood as described here: [How to take derivative of multivariate normal density?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27436/how-to-take-derivative-of-multivariate-normal-density) .

However, I don't know how to calculate the coefficients matrix $A$ in each maximization step.
$$
\frac{ \partial {\bf L} }{ \partial {\boldsymbol A}} = -\frac{1}{2}
 \left(
\frac{\partial \left( {\boldsymbol y} - {\boldsymbol A\boldsymbol x} \right) 
{\boldsymbol \Sigma}^{-1} \left( {\boldsymbol y} - {\boldsymbol A\boldsymbol x}\right)
}{\partial {\boldsymbol A}} \right) $$

How can it be solved analytically and is it this approach correct in a ML estimation with the EM algorithm? I am really stuck and would appreciate any help.