# How does one differentiate the log likelihood of a multivariate normal density?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-normal-distribution

I have looked at this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27436/how-to-take-derivative-of-multivariate-normal-density) already. However, my question is different.

Suppose $X\sim N(A\mu, C\Sigma C^T)$ (multivariate normal), where $\mu$ is $n \times 1 $, $A$ is $n \times n$, $C$ is $n \times p$ and $\Sigma$ is $p \times p$.

The log-loglikelihood that I derived is as follow (ignoring constants):

$$\ell = -\log \Big( \det \big[C \Sigma C^T \big] \Big) - (x-A\mu)^T (C \Sigma C^T)^{-1}(x-A\mu)$$.

**My Question is:** how can I differentiate the log-likelihood with respect to not only $\Sigma$ but also $A$ and $C$ ? i.e. How can I get the following

1. $$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial\Sigma}$$
2. $$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial A}$$
3. $$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial C}$$

And how should the terms be rearranged such that $A, C, \Sigma$ will be on one side after differentiation ?